# Cascading actions with bookmarks in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

The problem is the following:

Let's consider 2 sets of images embedded in a PowerBI file .pbix:

**Set 1**: Img1, Img2

**Set 2**: Img3, Img4, Img5, Img6

For each combination of 2 images between the two sets, we want to set an action (to a bookmark) to display a corresponding visual.

So here, we have these combinations:

(Img1, Img3) -> display Viz1.3

(Img1, Img4) -> display Viz1.4

(Img1, Img5) -> display Viz1.5

(Img1, Img6) -> display Viz1.6

(Img2, Img3) -> display Viz2.3

(Img2, Img4) -> display Viz2.4

(Img2, Img5) -> display Viz2.5

(Img2, Img6) -> display Viz2.6

Let's suppose that we have selected (Img1, Img3) and then we select (click) Img2.

How can we keep the selection on Img3 in order to display Viz2.3 ?

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Each image can, I'm pretty sure, only trigger one bookmark. If I'm reading right, I think you need to duplicate the images and hide/show according to the state of the display.
For example in the example above, if the display is Viz1.3 and you click image 2, the updates would be to the viz and to the images in set 2:

```
Viz1.3 -> Viz2.3   
Img3.1 -> Img3.2    
Img4.1 -> Img4.2   
Img5.1 -> Img5.2    
Img6.1 -> Img6.2
```

And if you updated from there by clicking Img4 to get to Viz2.4, you'd have to update the images in set one

```
Viz2.3 -> Viz2.4 
Img1.3 -> Img1.4  
Img2.3 -> Img2.4
```

So, ultimately, you'd need four version of each image in set one (one for each in set two) and two of each in set two (to match set one). And though you're only showing 6 at any given time, that's 16 which is twice as many as you have visuals. But if you have to have it that way for UX, then I can't think of another way to do it.

| **Image** | **Bookmark** |
|-----------|--------------|
| Img1.3    | Viz1.3       |
| Img1.4    | Viz1.4       |
| Img1.5    | Viz1.5       |
| Img1.6    | Viz1.6       |
| Img2.3    | Viz2.3       |
| Img2.4    | Viz2.4       |
| Img2.5    | Viz2.5       |
| Img2.6    | Viz2.6       |
| Img3.1    | Viz1.3       |
| Img3.2    | Viz2.3       |
| Img4.1    | Viz1.4       |
| Img4.2    | Viz2.4       |
| Img5.1    | Viz1.5       |
| Img5.2    | Viz2.5       |
| Img6.1    | Viz1.6       |
| Img6.2    | Viz2.6       |

[Showing or hiding bookmarks by screen state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSdK5.png)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The thing is I need to use a combination of both sets of buttons. From Viz1.3, I need to change the selection from Img1 to Img2 (Set 1) and keep the selection on Img3 (Set 2) to display Viz2.3. Then from Viz2.3, I need to keep the selection on Img2 (Set 1) and change the selection from Img3 to Img4 (Set 2) to display Viz2.4. So in your example, we have 4 configurations (selections) that lead to 4 different visualizations.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear enough. I think the solution to your problem involves swapping versions of the images as well as swapping the visualisations. So, selecting a different image in set 2, say from 3->4 swaps the viz from 3 to 4 but also swaps the images in set 1 to the versions with the bookmarks that go to 1.4 and 2.4.  I'll edit my answer to expand/

Comment: Thank you so much for your good solution. As I understand, you are supposing that for instance, to go to Viz2.4, you have to swap with 1 click on Img2.4 or Img4.2. Right ? But it would be nicer to swap in 2 clicks. Both sets of images are independent, they are not merged together! Here is the path to go from Viz1.2 to Viz2.4: initially Viz1.2 is displayed -> click on Img2 -> Viz2.2 is displayed -> click on Img4 -> Viz2.4 is displayed. Is it more clear now ? Not sure if there is a solution, it's a kind of dependency between bookmarks. Maybe do you have another shot with my last example ?

Comment: The way I'm envisioning it you'd still need two clicks, because both of those bookmark-images wouldn't be visible at the same time.

Comment: You'd only ever have six images visible. Starting at image 1.3, only bookmark images **1.3, 2.3** | **3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1** would be visible.  
To get to viz2.4, you'd click bookmark **2.3** to hide viz 1.3, show viz2.3, hide the x.1 versions of set 2 bookmarks - **3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1** - and in the same positions, show the x.2 versions **3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2**.  
Then bookmark 4.2 hides viz2.3, shows viz2.4 & swaps set 1 x.3 bookmarks for the x.4 ones